# Why was this Reopen review item invalidated?

Tags: support, bug, review, reopen

From the [timeline](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/111412/timeline) of [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/a-word-that-means-a-huge-amount-of-technical-emigrants/111414#111414), it seems the Reopen review which was initiated after my edit became *invalidated*.

Any idea how this could happen? Three reviewers have voted to reopen, but the question isn't open yet. No other events in the timeline could have interfered with the review somehow. The expected behaviour is that the review continues, until five people vote to reopen, the question is reopened outside the queue, or three people vote 'Leave Closed'.

[image: timeline of the question]
[image: reopen review queue]

Comment: I've been seeing a fair few reviews get invalidated for no reason I can determine. May need to investigate more thoroughly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### A tale of complexity and unintended consequences

The review task was added in response to [this edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/111412/timeline#history_6ca36abd-c85d-4622-a537-6196ad47d838) which you made.

Which is a good thing, generally. That edits can result in the review of a previously-closed post.

However...

There's a check, in the logic that determines whether an edit *qualifies* to do this, which excludes edits by folks who've also *flagged* the post. And by "flagged" I mean not just Very Low Quality flags and spam flags, but also close and reopen votes (which internally are just types of flags). The only flag that *doesn't* result in an edit being ignored is "in need of moderator intervention". The idea here is to avoid taking the actions of someone who is, say, editing vile language out of a post and turning it into an implicit request to see *more* of that sort of thing.

And this is still all well and good, except for the bit where it doesn't distinguish between flags raised *before* the edit and flags raised *after* the edit. Or indeed, flags raised *after the edit had already put the question into review*.

So what happened here is, you edited the question, and then came back a bit later after the question had entered review and voted to reopen it. And... The system said, "Oh no, same person flagged and edited, can't count the edit" - and now there was no reason to have a review.

But wait! Don't reopen votes normally trigger a review? So what if the edit is no longer valid; there's three votes! Weeeelll... Turns out the logic that checks for *votes* that would trigger a review has a time-limit on it that's meant to prevent a question from entering review for at least 15 minutes after the first vote is cast, to give things time to happen organically and such.

...And all of the votes came in within 15 minutes. Within two minutes, actually. So at the point when the edit was no longer valid, the votes weren't *yet* valid.

Thus, the review task became invalid. And since all of the votes happened after the question was already *in* review, they didn't count either - otherwise, there'd be no getting questions out of review if they got even a single vote, no matter how many people said "leave closed".

...And therein lies the bug: a conflict between two criteria for *allowing* a question into review inadvertently caused the question to drop out.

### So what should we do about this?

- Well, we could just ignore flags that happen after an edit. The edit only counts if it happens after the post is already closed, so it'd be a pretty rare occurrence for (for example), someone to edit a question and then decide it not only needed to be closed but also deleted. One might imagine a scenario involving spam or something I guess.
- We could also just ignore *reopen* flags when it comes to invalidating edits. This would allow someone to potentially put a question through review *twice* if they voted to reopen then, after that failed and their vote aged away, edited. In practice, this would require both patience and precise timing - there's only 5 days after a question's creation where edits work to put a question into review, and [aging doesn't start for four days after the last vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away)... So the question'd have to be closed immediately, then you'd have to cast your reopen vote pretty quickly thereafter, the question would have to go through review promptly, get *no more* reopen votes for four days, and then you'd have a bit less than a day to make your edit and hope the review went your way... 'cause on day 5, the task would once again become invalid. In spite of this obscure loophole, I kinda prefer this option: it's dead-simple.
- Or we could drop the 15-minute delay, or make it based on the time the question was *closed* instead of when an edit or vote was cast. This is the worst option, IMHO: generally-speaking, you only get one shot in review, so you want to give folks time to make *all* necessary edits or finish up any discussions in comments before you fire that off.

Comment: Wow. Many thanks for your lengthy explanation. I had no idea that it would be so complicated and initially blamed it on cosmic rays. When such issues happen at our projects, I usually just tell the customer 'some miraculous coincidence of events happened; we took some measures to prevent it the next time', and that's it. I prefer the second option as well, and hope that it will be implemented soon / in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: I like the option of ignoring reopen flags for invalidating  edits. I don't see a question getting reviewed twice as a huge problem given the typical size of our review queues and the complexity of making it happen on purpose.

Comment: @Shog9 Was one of these options ever implemented?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, @TylerH

Comment: The 5 day timeframe for edits pushing questions into the reopen queue mentioned in this post is no longer accurate. That timeframe has been extended to 70 days as of probably more than a year ago. It was progressively increased to that value over time. Please see [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/271271) for a description of the criteria for which edits put questions into the reopen queue.

Comment: @Glorfindel it wasn't quite 6-8 weeks, but this will be fixed in our upcoming review queue changes. I've explained in detail in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410755/3023052).

Comment: @KylePollard thank you for the update. I distinctly remember this Q&A as one of the first 'complicated' bugs/features in the system I reported (probably because of the response it got), I'm happy to see it resolved in whatever timespan :)